# CentOS RVM Error: Unknown ruby string (do not know how to handle): ruby-2.1.0

Tags: centos, rvm, gemset

I am setting up a rails app on a CentOS server.

We have installed rvm and ruby-2.1.0.

From my app directory when I try to create a gemset or use a gemset etc. I keep getting the following message:

Unknown ruby string (do not know how to handle): ruby-2.1.0.

If I do `rvm -list`, I get following:

```
rvm rubies

    =* ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]
```

Not sure then why I keep getting the errors about Uknown ruby. Btw, the Gemfile of the app has following line (for the benefit of Heroku I think):

```
ruby '2.1.0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across the same issue and filed it at https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3244.

This appears to be a bug in rvm 1.26.7 and as a workaround, you can downgrade to 1.26.6 by running:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --version 1.26.6
rvm reload
```

Edit:
  RVM 1.26.8 was releases and fixed this issue, running `rvm get stable` is the preferred fix now.

Comment: Np. Also, this is fixed in RVM 1.26.8+ now.

Comment: ...Well, for posterity, I see this error in 1.26.10, also on Centos.  So I would say that it wasn't fixed after all.